# Algorithm to Decompose Complex Polygons

Tags: c#, geometry, triangulation, polygons

I am trying to create the polygons for a Doom 2 level from the information contained in the WAD file. I have the walls done, all that is left is the 'flats', the floor and ceiling areas. A Doom map is divided into 'sectors', each evaluates to a flat, complex polygon.

It would be easy enough to decompose a simple, convex polygon into triangles, as there are many algorithms for this. But many of the sector polys are concave, and some even have 'holes' where other sectors are within them. Here is an example, with a particularly complex poly shown in orange: http://screencast.com/t/BNKuzRVy8

Can anyone recommend an algorithm, or better yet C# code, that will decompose this kind of complex poly into triangles?

I know that the WAD file includes NODE, SEG, SUBSECTOR information, etc. that indirectly describes a breakdown in this fashion. But it is particularly complex. I don't need the b-tree structure. I would like to avoid having to parse all of this information out and piece it together, since I have the complex poly structure from the sector info alone.

Comment: After some wrangling, I managed to solve the 'holes' problem by cutting the containing polygon into two halves around each hole. 

After this, garden-variety concave triangulation algorithms worked fine. I can't mark as answered yet because I don't have the SO reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for Ear Clipping triangulation method, a good start point is this David Elbery [article](http://www.geometrictools.com/Documentation/TriangulationByEarClipping.pdf).